# Google Sheets use formula results in another formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, string-formatting, number-formatting

Is there any way to get the value from a cell that has a formula in it to be used in another formula?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jkRAY0REiVHh7jN00Qtsa_OKiGObhHXYRF-qMxyk-r8/edit?usp=sharing

If you check cell D1, it has 0 in it I assume because it cannot get the value from the if() function in the formula for the range.

Thank you!

Comment: What you are asking or trying to describe is not clear without context. (And it seems to me that, given your minimal post sample, the value in C1 would be 4, not 3. Please consider sharing a link to your spreadsheet (or to a sample spreadsheet that mimics your real spreadsheet and contains enough *realistic* data to illustrate the problem you are trying to solve, and which contains your hand-entered results reflecting what you would like a formula to be doing).

Comment: C1 should give 4 since B1 is 2 (1+1), A1=1, A2=1.  Add those up and you get 4. Whenever you refer to a cell, the value used is the output of whatever formula is in it.

Comment: @ErikTyler, You're correct, it's been a long week. I added a spreadsheet with the actual use case.

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Should be public now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B50)
```

or:

```
=INDEX(SUM(B1:B50*1))
```

or change your IF to:

```
=IF(A1 < TODAY(), 2500, 0)
```

tho B1 should be:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A="",,IF(A1:A < TODAY(), 2500, 0)))
```

Comment: Ugh Thank you. The last suggestion worked. Didn't even realize I put those numbers in quotes.